# Redundant nullcheck with != null and ?.let?

Tags: kotlin

Does the first nullcheck make sense here?

```
error.timeoutInSeconds != null -> {
    error.timeoutInSeconds?.let {
        doWithNonNullTimeout(it)
    } ?: doWithNull("Timeout is null")
}
```

When I am not wrong, the second statement

```
doWithNull("Timeout is null")
```

is never being reached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This branch will only be called if `timeoutInSeconds` is non-null, so why would you expect `doWithNull` to ever be called? By the way, the `?.let {} ?: …` pattern is error prone and should not be used as an alternative to if/else. Because if the last expression of your lambda happens to evaluate to null, then both branches are run. `?.also` would be safer, but is less readable than if/else. Example:

```
foo.bar?.let {
    someBarFunction() // maybe it returns null as a side-effect
} ?: doSomethingAssumingBarIsNull()

// in this case, both someBarFunction() and doSomethingAssumingBarIsNull() are called
```

When working with a mutable nullable property or nullable property from another class you can do one of these to do it safely:

```
foo.bar.let { bar ->
    if (bar != null) {
        // use smart-cast not-null bar
    } else {
        // do something when bar is null
    }
}

// or
val bar = foo.bar
if (bar != null) {
    // use smart-cast not-null bar
} else {
    // do something when bar is null
}

// or this, but I don't think it's as readable as either of the above
foo.bar?.also { 
    // use not-null it
} ?: // do something when bar is null
```

Not sure what to suggest as your alternative because it’s not clear why you would have tried to handle a null case in a branch of your `when` where you already know it’s not null.

Comment: Isn't there a (rare but possible) race condition if `error.timeoutInSeconds` is updated by another thread? (In fact, avoiding potential race conditions is one of the benefits of using `let` — or a temporary variable — instead of repeating expressions like this.)

Comment: @gidds, yes, that's why I'm reluctant to suggest something without knowing the conditions. If `timeoutInSeconds` is mutable, I would think in most situations, you'd want to copy it to a local variable before entering the `when` expression, so it's stable throughout this logic. But it's possible they really do want to allow it to change concurrently and enter this doWithNull branch as an exit.